# Numpy: Making overlapping vectorized modifications to an existing numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm interested in knowing if its possible to modify individual indices of a numpy array in a manner flexible enough to modify the same index multiple times:

```
import numpy as np

zeros = np.zeros(10)
indices = np.array([0,0])
adders = np.array([5,8])
```

indexing `adders` in this way can give you a sum of 10

```
In [17]: adders[indices]
Out[17]: array([5, 5])
```

but modifying the same index on `zeros` twice will only yield a single modification

```
zeros[indices] += adders[indices]
zeros
Out[19]: array([5., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

I understand this can be done via a simple for loop, but is there any numpy functionality for this?

Comment: Look up `np.add.at`

Comment: thank you @hpaulj `np.add.at(zeros, indices, adders[indices])` was the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out

```
np.add.at(zeros, indices, adders[indices])
```